# UPDATE statement under a transaction running indefinitely

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sqlperformance

I am facing issue with ever-running query in one stored procedure (using SQL Server 2005).

In this stored procedure there are many UPDATE statements and few INSERT statements running under one Transaction.

When debugging the stored procedure, I found that there is one specific UPDATE query which is running indefinitely as shown below.

```
BEGIN TRAN  
...   
...-- some INSERT & UPDATE statements   

 UPDATE PIH
        SET PIH.RemittanceHeaderID = RD.RemittanceHeaderID
        FROM TempPayroll TP 
            INNER JOIN RemittanceDetails RD  ON TP.UniqueID = RD.PLInvoiceDetailID 
            INNER JOIN PLInvoiceHeader PIH  ON RD.PLInvoiceUniqueID = PIH.InvoiceUniqueID AND PIH.CompanyCode = TP.CompanyCode
        WHERE TP.PLSelfBill = 1 
            AND TP.UsePLPaymentTerms = 1
            AND RD.PLInvoiceDetailID IS NOT NULL
            AND TP.RecordType LIKE 'INVOICE%'
            AND RD.RecordType LIKE 'INVOICE%'  
  ... --some UPDATE statements
COMMIT TRAN
```

However, when I remove the `CompanyCode` condition the stored procedure is working fast with no issues. Also if I execute just this statement alone under a transaction separately it is running fine.

There are around 240 matching records for this query. Each table contains just 30k - 50k records.

How do I debug the query and how to fix it?

Why just that JOIN condition (`CompanyCode`) is creating this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a locking issue.

Comment: @scsimon I have already tried adding NOLOCK to the first two tables but still the same issue.

Comment: Do you have an Indexes you the tables? Can you post them? Is Company Code the same data type in both `TempPayroll ` and `PLInvoiceHeader ` (for example `varchar(20)`, `int`)?

Comment: I wouldn’t do that Sanjay

Comment: @Larnu  Both tables have the same datatype for companycode - varchar(20). There are two related indexes on PLInvoiceHeader. **Index 1** - nonclustered located on PRIMARY, Index keys - CompanyCode. **Index 2** - nonclustered, unique, unique key located on PRIMARY, Index keys - InvoiceUniqueID, CompanyCode. There are no Indexes on Temppayroll except the primary key (which is not related to Companycode).

Comment: Is the relationship between `PLInvoiceHeader.CompanyCode` and `TempPayroll.CompanyCode` a 1-to-1 or 1-to-many relationship?

Comment: @3BK There are several databases with the same schema. In other databases there are multiple CompanyCode values as there are multiple companies. In the current scenario (database), there is only one Company so the CompanyCode is same value for all the records in both the tables. For e.g. the CompanyCode is 'BGI' which is same for all the records in both tables.